# After installing pyqt5, designer.exe cannot run

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

- python3.9.5

I installed pyqt5 in pycharm and want to use QT designer.
After adding an external tool, I found that I couldn't run the tool

Pycharm reports the following error: process finished with exit code - 1073741571 (0xc00000fd).

Then I tried to double-click (designer.exe) in the project folder, but it still couldn't run.

Show in Windows log

Bad application name: designer.exe, version: 5.15.2.0, timestamp:    0x5fa5117b

Error module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1566, timestamp: 0x1be73aa8

Exception code: 0xc000000fd

Error offset: 0x000000000002b665

I don't know what the problem is. I've tried many methods and still can't run. I don't know what to do.

Comment: How did you install PyQt5 Designer?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install PyQt5 Designer with pip? Installing it with pip should solve the issue. [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5Designer/)

```
pip install PyQt5Designer
```